# Android: get an empty database from local server

Tags: android, sqlite, inputstream, outputstream

I'm following this guide [Tutorial](http://dixitpatel.com/?p=128) to create a fetch database function within my android application

Here is the similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117067/androidhow-to-download-the-file-from-the-server-and-save-it-in-specific-folder), but for him, problem is  the url is not a file, its a directory.

When my application running, it need auto download a database file from my local server which directory is `192.168.1.150/db/wifin.db`, i tested from my browser download file correctly, but my application only can get a empty database with a correct name.

Affection: Because of this problem, makes my program a null exception on null sqlite table

**Here is my code.**

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
    this.getReadableDatabase();
    try{
        copyDataBase();}
    catch (IOException e){
        throw new Error("Error copying database");}
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //url of my webserver link point to my db
        Thread dx = new Thread() {
            public void run(){
                try{

                    URL url = new URL("192.168.1.150/db/wifin.db");

                    //open a connection
                    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

                    connection.connect();

                    //Open your local db as the input stream
                    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

                    // Path to the just created empty db
                    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

                    //Open the empty db as the output stream
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

                    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                    long total = 0;
                    int count;
                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();}
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("ERROR ON DOWNLOADING FILES", "ERROR IS" +e);
                }
            }
        };
        dx.start();
}
```

**here is the cat log**

```
10-13 22:41:34.527: W/System.err(28533): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 192.168.1.150/db/wifin.db
10-13 22:41:34.527: W/System.err(28533):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:178)
10-13 22:41:34.527: W/System.err(28533):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:127)
10-13 22:41:34.527: W/System.err(28533):    at com.example.Wifin.DataBaseHelper$1.run(DataBaseHelper.java:110)
10-13 22:41:34.537: I/ERROR ON DOWNLOADING FILES(28533): ERROR ISjava.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 192.168.1.150/db/wifin.db
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.150/db/wifin.db");`
and go to delete <del>connection.connect()</del>;
that will works