# store image to sqlite type blob error?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

i try to store json data plus image to sqlite, my image use type blob, my json data string success but my image failed or null, what i should do ?

LogCat error

```
01-03 04:22:54.827: W/System.err(22776): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.2.2:81/bantulfolder/sqlitepk1.JPG
01-03 04:22:54.846: W/System.err(22776):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
01-03 04:22:54.846: W/System.err(22776):    at com.dbp.insertalldata.MainActivity.getLogoImage(MainActivity.java:138)
01-03 04:22:54.865: W/System.err(22776):    at com.dbp.insertalldata.MainActivity.access$2(MainActivity.java:133)
01-03 04:22:54.865: W/System.err(22776):    at com.dbp.insertalldata.MainActivity$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:115)
01-03 04:22:54.865: W/System.err(22776):    at com.dbp.insertalldata.MainActivity$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
01-03 04:22:54.865: W/System.err(22776):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
01-03 04:22:54.865: W/System.err(22776):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
01-03 04:22:54.876: W/System.err(22776):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
```

my code activity in bellow

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button Btngetdata;

    // URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2:81/bantulfolder/alldata.php";

    private String IMAGEURL = "http://10.0.2.2:81/bantulfolder/";

    private byte[] logoImage;

    byte[] gambarku;

    // JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_DATA = "data";
    public static final String TAG_IDT = "idt";
    public static final String TAG_IDL = "idl";
    public static final String TAG_NAMA = "nama";
    public static final String TAG_ALAMAT = "alamat";
    public static final String TAG_GAMBAR = "gambar";
    public static final String TAG_DESKRIPSI = "deskripsi";
    public static final String TAG_LATITUDE = "latitude";
    public static final String TAG_LONGTITUDE = "longtitude";

    JSONArray user = null;

    private DatabaseHandler databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.this);

        Btngetdata = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new JSONParse().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                // Getting JSON Array
                user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);
                // loop through all users
                for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing JSON item in a Variable
                    String idt = c.getString(TAG_IDT);
                    String idl = c.getString(TAG_IDL);
                    String nama = c.getString(TAG_NAMA);
                    String alamat = c.getString(TAG_ALAMAT);
                    String gambar = c.getString(TAG_GAMBAR);
                    String deskripsi = c.getString(TAG_DESKRIPSI);
                    String latitude = c.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
                    String longtitude = c.getString(TAG_LONGTITUDE);

                    logoImage = getLogoImage(IMAGEURL+gambar);

                    databaseHelper.saveCategoryRecord(idt, idl, nama, alamat, gambar, logoImage, deskripsi, latitude, longtitude);

                    // Set JSON Data in TextView
                //  uid.setText(idt);
                    //name1.setText(name);
                    // email1.setText(email);
                    // show the values in our logcat
                    Log.e(TAG, "nama >>>> " + idt + "  alamat>>>>> " + nama);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

databae handler, i use for create table and save image

```
public class DatabaseHandler {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bantul";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tb_alldata";
    public static final String TAG_IDT = "idt";
    public static final String TAG_IDL = "idl";
    public static final String TAG_NAMA = "nama";
    public static final String TAG_ALAMAT = "alamat";
    public static final String TAG_GAMBAR = "gambar";
    public static final String TAG_FILE_GAMBAR = "file_gambar";
    public static final String TAG_DESKRIPSI = "deskripsi";
    public static final String TAG_LATITUDE = "latitude";
    public static final String TAG_LONGTITUDE = "longtitude";

    Category openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context){
        openHelper = new Category(context);
        database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    public void saveCategoryRecord(String idt, String idl, String nama, String alamat, String gambar, byte[] logoImage,
            String deskripsi, String latitude, String longtitude) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(TAG_IDT, idt);
        contentValues.put(TAG_IDL, idl);
        contentValues.put(TAG_NAMA, nama);
        contentValues.put(TAG_ALAMAT, alamat);
        contentValues.put(TAG_GAMBAR, gambar);
        contentValues.put(TAG_FILE_GAMBAR, logoImage);
        contentValues.put(TAG_DESKRIPSI, deskripsi);
        contentValues.put(TAG_LATITUDE, latitude);
        contentValues.put(TAG_LONGTITUDE, longtitude);
        database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        }
    public Cursor getTimeRecordList() {
        return database.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        }

    private class Category extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public Category(Context context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( "
                    + TAG_IDT + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                    + TAG_IDL + " INTEGER, "+ TAG_NAMA + " TEXT, "+ TAG_ALAMAT + " TEXT, "+ TAG_GAMBAR + " TEXT, "
                    + TAG_FILE_GAMBAR + " BLOB, "+ TAG_DESKRIPSI + " TEXT, " + TAG_LATITUDE + " INTEGER, "
                    + TAG_LONGTITUDE + " INTEGER )" );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }
}
```

and class JSONParser for parser json data, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **BLOB** data type is actually used to store binary data not a URL that is represented as **TEXT**.

You need to supply code for downloading that image and then save the path as **TEXT** not the binary data itself.

For how to download a file you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117067/androidhow-to-download-the-file-from-the-server-and-save-it-in-specific-folder).

Comment: It's not a good practice to download the image in the internal storage. You can make use of `getExternalFilesDir()`. Check this link before proceeding http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html but anyway you can replace `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( file);` with the `openFileOutput("imagename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`