# get text from a file with htt post response android

Tags: android, file, http, server

I was looking and I couldn't find that a way to get a text from files in a server and get it via http post response then save it to a file in android. A time ago I saw it was possible, but I can't find the post anymore.

Could you help me please or let me know were it's explained it would be much appreciated. I just want the content of the file no to download it.

Comment: First think of database data, you access data and then send to client. Similarly think of file, you access file content which is store in server and send it to client :)

Comment: try this links
1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117067/androidhow-to-download-the-file-from-the-server-and-save-it-in-specific-folder 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472226/how-to-save-file-from-website-to-sdcard